# Concatenate Arguments on Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have an AWS Lambda function that is calling an AWS Glue job like this:

```
response = client.start_job_run(
JobName = glueJobName,<br />
Arguments = {<br />
                '--INPUT': 's3://'+OriginBucket+'/'+'|'+Dependencies+'|'+'/YEAR='+year+'/MONTH='+month+'/DAY='+day+'/',<br />
                '--OUTPUT': 's3://'+DestinationBucket+'/'+DestinationTable+'/YEAR='+year+'/MONTH='+month+'/DAY='+day+'/'<br />
           }<br />
```

`OriginBucket`, `DestinationBucket` and `DestionationTable` are strings and `Dependencies` is a string with the following format:

```
"xxx/xxx/xxx/folder|yyy/yyy/yyy/folder|zzz/zzz/zzz/folder"
```

I did this because different tables are going to be created with different Glue jobs and those tables (files in the destination bucket) needs different amounts of origin files to be created and the Lambda function is one. I hope this is understood.

Finally in every Glue job I have something like this:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','INPUT', 'OUTPUT'])<br />
sc = SparkContext()<br />
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)<br />
spark = glueContext.spark_session<br />
job = Job(glueContext)<br />
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)<br />

INIT = args['INPUT'].split('|') --- NOTICE HERE THAT EVERY PART THAT I NEED IS SEPARATED WITH A PIPE, INCLUDING THE DIFERENT DEPENDENCIES<br />
BUCKET = INIT[0] -- s3://xx_bucket/<br />
PART1 = ENTRADA[1] -- xxx/xxx/xxx/folder<br />
PART2 = ENTRADA[2] -- yyy/yyy/yyy/folder<br />
PART3 = ENTRADA[3] -- zzz/zzz/zzz/folder<br />
PARTITIONS = ENTRADA[4] --/YEAR=2022/MONTH=08/DAY=23/<br />
OPUT= args['OUTPUT']<br />

df0 = spark.read.orc(BUCKET,PART1,PARTITIONS)
```

In this last sentence is where I want to read the files in the bucket formed by `BUCKET,PART1,PARTITIONS = 's3://xx_bucket/xxx/xxx/xxx/folder/YEAR=2022/MONTH=08/DAY=23/'` but it gives me the error:

> An error occurred while calling o74.orc. assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths:

I think this is because I printed `(BUCKET,PART1,PARTITIONS)` and what is returned is actually:
`'s3://xx_bucket/ xxx/xxx/xxx/folder/ YEAR=2022/MONTH=08/DAY=23/'` with spaces in between.

Does someone have an idea on how to overcome this issue? Maybe a way to iterate over that tuple and concat the strings?

Comment: `df0 = spark.read.orc(f"{BUCKET}{PART1}{PARTITIONS}")`

Comment: you can use + to concatenate the strings. 'a' + 'b'  -> 'ab'